# Does an unused 120 Days work permit (Zurich, Switzerland) require a cooling off period?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, switzerland, work-permit

I have a L4 visa for 120 days for my work, but I did not use the visa due to Covid situation. For next year, if I plan to get another L4 visa (120 days), will there be any cooling off period required? For a used work permit, there will be a 12 months cooling off period, but what about for an unused work permit?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you had a visa (cat. D) but you never arrived in Switzerland and never applied/obtained the residence permit?

Comment: I didn't even apply visa, Just received work permit. Next step was Visa processing but it didnt happen due to Covid.

Comment: So you received an Einreiseerlaubnis?